# Issue with ggplot with discrete x-axis in date format (yyyy-mm-dd)

Tags: r, ggplot2, line

I have a data frame like below. I need to plot a line plot using ggplot each line showing for each year (i.e. 2014, 2015 etc) with different colors for each year.

I cannot connect the points by a line with my code showing below. But, it does plot the points only with different colors for each year. This may be a simple thing but I just cannot figure this out.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

plot.data <- melt(Table_1, id.vars = 'Day Obs')
ggplot(plot.data, aes(x = `Day Obs`, y = value)) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = `Day Obs`, y = value, colour = variable),size=1.0) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = `Day Obs`, y = value, colour = variable),size=2.3)
```

Table_1:

```
Day Obs     2014    2015   2016   2017    2018
2018-08-01    NA     NA     NA     NA    1.002    
2018-08-03    NA     0.85   NA     NA       NA
2018-08-06    NA     NA     NA     NA      0.9
2018-08-07    NA     NA    0.78   0.88      NA
.
.
```

Comment: please make your dataset reproducible

Comment: @ kath, I tried your suggestion but no luck. Thanks though.

Comment: i dont understand what is the `value`?

Comment: @Salman. When you melt Table-1 you get "plot.data". In that "plot.data", the three column names are Day Obs, variable and value. Just try with a sample data set. Hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have missing values i between observations and `geom_line` then doesn't connect the points (as information is missing). This can be seenfor the year 2018:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

plot.data <- melt(Table_1, id.vars = 'Day Obs')
plot.data[plot.data$variable == 2018, ]
#       Day Obs variable value
# 17 2018-08-01     2018 1.002
# 18 2018-08-03     2018    NA
# 19 2018-08-06     2018 0.900
# 20 2018-08-07     2018    NA
```

Here the information for 2018-08-03 is missing explicitly. Therfore there is no connection between the points, if we plot them.

```
ggplot(plot.data, aes(x = `Day Obs`, y = value, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.0) +
  geom_point(size = 2.3)
```

[image]

You can remove the explicit missing values and it works:

```
ggplot(plot.data[!is.na(plot.data$value), ], 
       aes(x = `Day Obs`, y = value, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.0) +
  geom_point(size = 2.3)
```

[image]

**Data**

```
Table_1 <- structure(list(`Day Obs` = structure(c(17744, 17746, 17749, 17750), class = "Date"), 
                          `2014` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                          `2015` = c(NA, 0.85, NA, NA), 
                          `2016` = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.78), 
                          `2017` = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.88), 
                          `2018` = c(1.002, NA, 0.9, NA)), 
                     row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You nailed it. It worked. Thanks a bunch. I have a long way to go with ggplotting. :).